# react useEffect with async-await not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `useEffect` hooks in my component, which makes a API call and I want it to run only on first render. But I'm unable to make the API call. what am I missing here?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //should run on first render
    (async () => {
      const getAllSeasons = await getSeasonList();
      setSeasons(getAllSeasons);
    })();
  }, []);

  const getSeasonList = async () => {
    if (state && state?.seasonList) {
      return state?.seasonList;
    } else {
      const seasonData = await useSeasonService();
      if (seasonData?.status === "loaded") {
        return seasonData?.payload?.seasons || [];
      } else if (seasonData.status == "error") {
        return [];
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you share getSeasonList() functions's code?

Comment: do `console.log(getAllSeasons)` let see what you get

Comment: As I see you used useSeasonService() hook in a function. You are not allowed to do in react. hooks should be used directly inside a react element.

Comment: Can you please confirm on whether `useSeasonService` is a hook or another function with API call in it?

Comment: Provide whole component code please.

Comment: @cooskun good catch! I believe that's the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to fetch APIs using `fetch` method

```
fetch('https://apisaddress.me/api/')
  .then(({ results }) => consoe.log(results) ));
```

Another aproach is using `axios`

```
const Func= async ()=>{
   const response= await axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon? 
   limit=500&offset=200')
   this.setState({Data:response.data.results})
}


// npm install axios
```

Comment: you're missing the point here.. getSeasonList() does the fetch part

Comment: use axios instead i'm also using this in my project

Answer (score -1):

Make the new function and clean all code from useEffect and put inside that function. and then call the function inside the useEffect. Like:

```
const sampleCall = async () => {
  const getAllSeasons = await getSeasonList();
  setSeasons(getAllSeasons);
}
useEffect(() => {
  sampleCall()
}, [])
```

Follow these steps, if it is still not working then try to add seasons inside the useEffect array, [seasons].
Thank You.

Comment: async method can be called within useEffect

Answer (score -1):

1. `useEffect` works fine. The proof is here https://codesandbox.io/s/set-seasons-9e5cvn?file=/src/App.js.
   So, the problem is in `getSeasonList` function.
2. `await useSeasonService()` won't work. React Hooks names start with `use` word and can't be called inside functions or conditionally. `useSeasonService` is considered by React engine as a custom hook. Chek this for more details:
   https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook
3. Your code example doesn't show what `state` is and how it's initialized.
4. `state && state?.seasonList` check is redundant. `state?.seasonList` is enough.
5. It's a bad practice to put such complex logic as in `getSeasonList` into React components. You'd better use some state container (Recoil might be a good choice if you have some small non-related states in the app).

P.S. You wrote a poor description of the problem and then gave minuses for answers. That's not fair. Nobody would help you if you'll continue to do such thing. You gave 4 minuses and received 4 minuses in response. It's better to clarify what's wrong before giving a plus or minus to any answer.